# Восстановить значения после XOR

Tags: php

Ниже приведён код, нужно из полученного значения восстановить значения `'47533', '23182', '52170'`.

Скажите, как можно решить? Или же можно переделать алгоритм, основная задача из 3 чисел переменной `$a` получить одно, из которого можно восстановить начальные 3 числа. Известен только результат переменной `$result`.

```
$table = array(0x003b6c1c, 0x002def61, 0x006effa2, 0x0013045f, 0x00873358, 0x0039e1fd, 0x0061491a, 0x002608bf, 0x00254ed0, 0x004fc7dd, 0x00721a32, 0x0018dce3, 0x001328bc, 0x003e288d, 0x0084387e, 0x004c11e3);  
$a = array('47533', '23182', '52170');  
$result = "";  
for($i = 0;$i < count($a);$i++)  
{  
  $result += $a[$i]^$table[$i];  
}  
echo $result; //Результат: 14139400
```

Comment: Какова область определения исходных "чисел"? `unsigned word`?

Comment: Из того, что есть, восстановить исходные числа нельзя.

Comment: Дана сумма 13, восстановите исходные слагаемые количеством три.

Comment: Не обязательно упираться именно в этот алгоритм, нужно решение самой задачи, а вот алгоритм сам можно переделать. Главное, чтобы получилось 1 значение и не большу 20 миллиардов.

Comment: Я же спросил, каковы размеры/границы исходных чисел?

Comment: Последнее число должно быть в пределах от -20 миллиардов до 20 миллиардов. А начальные числа могут быть длинной максимум до 8-12 цифр.

Comment: Очевидно, у результата недостаточный объём информации, чтобы сохранить исходное состояние. Про 8 цифр ещё можно было думать.

Comment: Что можете посоветовать для решения?

Comment: Так же устроит решение, если можно как-то сократить число из 8-12 символов на 2 цифри, с возможностью восстановление в исходное состояние)

Comment: Возможно устроит решение, в котором результат не является числом? Например простой перевод в 62-ричную систему счисления (набор цифр [0-9a-zA-Z]) неплохо сократит строку.

Comment: нужно, чтобы результат был числом

Comment: Ваша задача решения не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

***Количество бит информации зашифрованного сообщения не может быть меньше совокупного количества бит исходных данных.***

> Сократить число из 8-12 символов на 2 цифры, с возможностью восстановления в исходное состояние

Продемонстрирую абсурдность постановки задачи:

Допустим существует такой алгоритм:

```
function shortBy2($number) {
  //return shortened;
}
function r($a) {/*implementation*/}

$input = 123456123456;
$r1 = shortBy2($input); // length is 10
$r2 = shortBy2($r1); // length is 8
$r3 = shortBy2($r2); // length is 6
$r4 = shortBy2($r3); // length is 4
$r5 = shortBy2($r4); // length is 2
```

Таким образом любое число можно сократить до одного из ста чисел.
Но по предположению мы можем восстановить исходное число:

```
$r1 == r(r(r(r($r5))));
```

однако очевидно, что при ста возможных значениях аргумента, мы получим не более 100 различных результатов "восстановления".

---

Есть, конечно, архиватор Бабушкина, но это засекреченные технологии.